# Create a group in address book for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am working in an iPhone application which uses adding contact to the address book. I have been able to add contacts to the address book but the problem I am facing is while adding a contact record to a group that I have created.

The contact is created under all contacts not within the group which have been created. Below is the code I have used

```
// create address book record
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 
// create a person  
ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();  
// first name of the new person
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"FirstName" , nil);
// his last name 
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty, @"LastName", nil);  
//add the new person to the record
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, nil); 

ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate(); //create a group 
ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty,@"My Group", &error); // set group's name 
ABGroupAddMember(group, person, &error); // add the person to the group         
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, group, &error); // add the group   

//save the record
ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, nil);  

// relase the ABRecordRef  variable
CFRelease(person);
```

Comment: you mean you can not add person to group right?

Comment: yes the person is not added to the group but it is added to the all contacts .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to save the Person to the address book before adding it to the group, this means you have to add an

```
ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, nil);
```

Before adding the person to the group, in your case it will be just before creating the group.

Comment: I have tried as you have mentioned but still it doesn't work the contact is saved in the all contacts not within the group

Comment: As for the person in the address book, you also need to save after adding the group, before adding the person to the group, everything need to be saved in the address book. So create the person, save. Create the group, save. Add the person to the group, save.

Comment: i tried it liked that also it still didnt work. Do you know any other way around in adding  contacts to the addressbook

Comment: This is the only way I know, but It's weird because I've tried what I said, and It worked, Xcode 4 + iOS SDK 4.3

Comment: A link to a sample I've tried and work, tell me if it works for you: http://cl.ly/67s8

Comment: Thank you very much .. the sample you had provided worked for me . :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is My test , I test it , it works well.

```
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFErrorRef error;
ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty,@"new group", &error);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(ab, group, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(ab, &error);
//Create new person and save to this group
ABRecordRef record = ABPersonCreate();
BOOL isSuccess ;

isSuccess  = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonNicknameProperty,@"GroupMember nick name", &error);
isSuccess = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty, @"Middle name", &error);

ABMutableMultiValueRef copyOfPhones = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);

CFTypeRef phone= CFSTR("123000222111");

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(copyOfPhones, phone,kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel,NULL);

isSuccess = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty, copyOfPhones, &error);

isSuccess = ABAddressBookAddRecord(ab, record, &error);
isSuccess = ABAddressBookSave(ab, &error);

ABGroupAddMember(group, record, &error);

NSLog(@"is success %d", isSuccess);

ABAddressBookSave(ab, &error);
CFRelease(group);
```

Comment: The problem with the above code is that is will create multiple groups with the name "My Group". It won't add the content to an existing group, which is what the original question asked. And where I'm stuck :-)