# Create contacts groups

Tags: ios, contacts, abaddressbook

```
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFErrorRef error;
ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty,@"new group", &error);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(ab, group, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(ab, &error);

CFRelease(group);
```

I try this code for creating contacts group. How ever I m not success. Need help on this.

UPDATE:

```
CFErrorRef error;
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL,&error);
ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty,@"new group", &error);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(ab, group, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(ab, &error);
NSLog(@"%@",error);
CFRelease(group);
```

now only print (null).....

Comment: You have an error parameter but you aren't checking it. I'd suggest that's the first thing to do. Also - check the documentation - ABAddressBookCreate() is deprecated.

Comment: Get idea from here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712740/create-a-group-in-address-book-for-iphone

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre I try that code in link. Contacts adding successfully how ever not create group.

Comment: Does the app have permission to access the Address book? Have a look at this answer to set it up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648244/programmatically-request-access-to-contacts Also, you should be checking the result of calls that have an error reference and check the error on failure; don't just log the error at the end.

Comment: yes the app has permission to access contacts.... and still no result..